# Flask-SQLAlchemy query in a many to many ITSELF relationship

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a many to many relationship to itself, that means, my model is User and one field is friends, which would be Users. I have done it the relationship but my problem comes when I try to do the query for the friends of an User. My model and the relation looks like this:

```
friendship = db.Table('friends',
Column('friend_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('monkeys.id')),
Column('myfriend_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('monkeys.id'))
)

class Monkey (db.Model):
    _tablename__ = "monkeys"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = Column(String(50), unique = True)
    email = Column(String(120), unique = True)
    password = Column(String(50))
    date = Column (DateTime(), default=datetime.now())

    friends = relationship('Monkey',
            secondary = friendship,
            primaryjoin = (friendship.c.friend_id == id),
            secondaryjoin = (friendship.c.myfriend_id == id),
            backref = backref('friendship', lazy = 'dynamic'),
            lazy = 'dynamic')
```

And from de view, if I want to do the query, I have tried with something

```
friends_list = Monkey.query.join(Monkey.friends).filter(Monkey.id == user.id).all()
```

Bu it does not work... any help please? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create join by yourself.

change lazy='joined' - items will be loaded “eagerly” in the same query as that of the parent.

When You get object Monkey you already have access to friends

```
monkey = session.query(Monkey).get(user.id)

friends_list =  monkey.friends
```

Comment: But I want to use another functions in the query, as "paginate" and "order_by" and it does not work with that call

Comment: You didn't mention this before :). 

Instead of using `friendship = db.Table()` create `class Friendship(db.Model):`.
This is explained in sqlalchemy [documentation](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/orm/relationships.html#association-object)

Comment: Then get access to the friends by `friends = session.query(Friendship).filter(Friendship.friend_id==user.id).all()`

Comment: Hi qwetty, first of all, thanks for the answer! But I have some "problems". I do not have to use the querys of sqlalchemy, but the flask-sqlalchemy. I does not change too much. About to change from `db.Table()` to a class, if you check the Many to Many relationship in the link that you wrote, It recomends have a relationship table, as I did.